# Cannot find module 'pouchdb-find'

Tags: pouchdb

I've installed ***pouchdb-find***. I'm importing that in my routes file..I can find it in `node_modules` and package.json but still I'm getting cannot find module pouchdb-find..At the same time it's not showing the same error for pouchdb..

- Why is that ?
- How to solve this ?
- Anyone please help ?

  `import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
    import PouchFind from 'pouchdb-find';
    import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';
    PouchDB.plugin(PouchFind);`

Comment: That's interesting. I'm using React Native in my project, not React, so I'm not sure if this will help you or not.

I'm using this syntax - 

    import PouchDB from "pouchdb-react-native";

    PouchDB.plugin(require("pouchdb-find"));

with the plugin and require all in one.